# Installing and activating themes on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Unity, how to do?

Tags: unity, themes, icons, gtk, cursor

There are lots of cursor, icon, window and GTK themes on the web and I downloaded some of them, but I do not know how to figure out if they are compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit Unity? Furthermore, in the beginning I used `Ubuntu Tweak Tool` to change the **cursor**, **icon**, **window** and **GTK themes**; however, I noticed that when I changed the cursor theme and hovered the cursor from one window to another its appearance changed. I was able to fix this by running the following command to set the cursor theme after setting it from `Ubuntu Tweak Tool`.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme

The output of the command was as follows: 

$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
There are 7 choices for the alternative x-cursor-theme (providing /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme).

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme     100       auto mode
  1            /etc/X11/cursors/core.theme                 30        manual mode
  2            /etc/X11/cursors/handhelds.theme            20        manual mode
  3            /etc/X11/cursors/redglass.theme             20        manual mode
  4            /etc/X11/cursors/whiteglass.theme           20        manual mode
  5            /usr/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme     30        manual mode
  6            /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme     100       manual mode
* 7            /usr/share/icons/mac-cursors/cursor.theme   90        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

And this made me wonder where to put the `cursor themes`, why the priority of each one is different and what the manual vs. auto mode standed for. Moreover, I was not sure where to put the `GTK` or `icon` theme files and I preferred to put them under `~/.icons` and I also have an unhidden `~/icons` directory containing `tar.gz` versions of various themes together with a `themes` directory (also containing themes in `tar.gz` format) in my home folder. I do not remember as of now if I put them myself or the system created them. I would be grateful and appreciate it if someone could explain how `update-alternatives` work and where are the **various themes** stored usually? Also in my opinion `Ubuntu Tweak Tool` is not that successful at changing themes, is there an alternative for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a new theme it would suffice to copy it to `~/.local/share/themes`, and activate it using Unity Tweak Tool. Running `update-alternatives` won't be necessary.

Some themes are available via PPAs. [Numix](https://numixproject.org/) for example.

PPAs usually install them in `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/icons/`, so it seems to me that your `~/icons` folder is one created by yourself

Furthermore `.$HOME/themes` and `$HOME/icons` paths are deprecated and will not be read in future releases.

Comment: Thanks I am actually using the global file and do not have an icons file under my home directory. Gsettings commands also work while setting the theme. I also answered my own question let me know if it needs editing I did not remember the step of changing the `.theme ` file.

Answer (score 1):

It install a theme here is what you need to do:

```
> tar xf package.tar.gz
> sudo mv package /usr/share/themes
```

to activate, open Unity Tweak Tool (UTT), and go to `Appearance` and then `Theme`. And select your desired theme (`package`)!

Comment: In order to get a consistent mouse cursor over all the open windows the following settings are necessary:
**1** sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
**2** gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "desired_theme"

After copying the theme under /usr/share/icons for global usage or under home directory as depicted by @reversiblean.

Comment: Thank you for this information... That never came up in my research, but now that I know.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a consistent mouse cursor over all the open windows the following settings are necessary:

1. Make sure that you copied the theme under `/usr/share/icons/desired_theme`
2. Under this directory there should be an **cursor.theme** file and it should contain the following(The Inherits line is the most important):

   [Icon Theme]

Name = Hackneyed 
Comment = Windows 3.x-inspired cursors 
Example = default 
Inherits = Hackneyed

3. Then the following commands should be run:

   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/desired_theme/cursor.theme 50

   sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme

   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "desired_theme"

Assuming the theme is already copied under `/usr/share/icons` for global usage or under home directory as depicted by @reversiblean.

**EDIT** Ubuntu Tweak Tools can also be used to accomplish the second step. However, first step can only be done on the CLI. I could not make some of the parts in coding format.